Who were the perpetrators of the violence and killings of the Bangladeshi protesters in 2024?
Protests were widespread in Bangladesh during June and July 2024, leading to violence which resulted in injuries and deaths.
Who ordered/orchestrated/masterminded whom to incite the killings?

"Who ordered/orchestrated/masterminded whom to incite the killings?" I simply note that killings could happen without being ordered, orchestrated, or masterminded about someone. This case could very well be different, but it is not at all an uncommon situation for their to be lots of violence resulting in injuries or deaths without a mastermind. Assuming that there is one, as this question does, gives it a somewhat conspiratorial tone.

As this is a recent and ongoing event it is going to be hard if not impossible to provide an answer at this time.

The news I am reading says "X Protesters died" or "Y People died" or "Z deaths have occurred" , where it is not clear who died how, When the count is available , the reason is strangely censored !

Democratically, Sheikh Hasina was elected by the Bangladeshi Electorate.  By a Maduro-style definition of democracy, depending on the PoV.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2018_Bangladeshi_general_election#Conduct  That's the 2nd Bangladeshi question you've asked with this very questionable general assertion as opening.  Not sure why you felt you had to open it that way.  To discredit protesters?

Too early to say, but given the Army general's public statement, I have a feeling they intend to find the police etc. responsible, possibly on Hasina's orders. https://www.voanews.com/a/bangladesh-pm-sheikh-hasina-resigns-interim-government-to-be-formed-/7730098.html Especially, since she fled the country. Quite possibly though, investigations may also take a long time and/or be buried.

"t is not clear who died how, When the count is available , the reason is strangely censored !" It is much easier to do a count than it id to figure out who died how. Censorship shouldn't be your first instinct.

I had only one question , which was listed in my earlier post. Everything else was context for that question , @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica , that question was closed to due various issues , I was told to ask 1 question per post , thus this post where I just copy pasted , hence wording will be mostly same. Why did I start that way ? Well . unpopular governments can/might/will get protesters almost immediately after the rigged elections. Since there was not much protests when elections got over , I assumed that the public were mostly in support. The scale of protests seemed incongruous to that.

It is okay for you to comment that the Army "intends" to hold the Police & Hasina responsible & to comment that investigations may be "buried" , @timetakesitstoll , since those are "compact" ways to talk in limited spaces , though when I include such words in the Post , there will be folks asking whether I am on this side or on that side : I am neither , I only want to know !

Unless someone has come out and stated that they ordered the killings or was behind it we are speculating on a current event.

People are encouraged to ask abut US Presidential Elections ( https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2661/brace-yourself-us-presidential-election-is-coming-up ) which is speculating on current event & future event , @JoeW , which is not a reason to not ask. Even when speculating . the answer could then be "NYT reports that nobody knows who did it" or "Sources suggest without evidence that X did it" or ETC. On a side note , I have no idea what to ask & what to include in the Post , because I am repeatedly accused of supporting some side or the other , which even I am not aware of.

That is not encouraging people to ask about US presidential elections rather a warning that they are upcoming and more low quality questions could come as a result. Regardless that doesn't change that we would be speculating and that repeating what the media said isn't always useful. If you want to fall back that the media says no one knows that doesn't answer your question and is rather a statement that not enough is known yet to answer the question.

(1) I think it encourages people to ask about US presidential elections , because otherwise that Post should say "such questions should be blindly closed with that (speculation + current event) reason" or "such questions are supporting X or Y & closed be closed due to that (purpose + promote discredit) reason" (2) When users report the media saying nothing is yet known , that will help (at least me) to know that I am not in a censorship bubble , @JoeW , what I am reading is actually what little is known. (3) When I am asking because I do not know , I am accused of bad faith , which is silly.

I disagree about it encouraging people to ask questions about the election as it was originally posted in response to an increased number of questions. I also disagree about an answer saying no one knows being useful as it is really saying that the news sources don’t know yet. And saying that it is speculation isn’t accusing you of asking in bad faith. I have never accused you of asking in bad faith.

@Prem The issue is that this site defines it as bad faith to ask a clearly loaded question. The question "Who ordered/orchestrated/masterminded whom to incite the killings?" is specifically seeking a leader to blame, followed by a subordinate person/group, with the word "incite" indicating it is not the group that did the killing that you're seeking to know about.  The bad faith component is that its biased and already suggests an answer. A possible rewrite to the question without bias would be "What do we know about the specific event or series of events that led up to the fatalities?"

Surely using the word "fatality" already assumes that somebody died ? That would be bias too. While a leader can incite a mob , a mob can incite itself too , @DavidS , hence it is not worth-while to avoid that word. Why is it wrong to ask about the leader & not wrong to ask about the group ? I may think of multiple ways it occurred (1) Hasina ordered her Supporters (2) Hasina ordered the Police/Amy (3) Mob acted by itself (4) Police/Amy did it while putting the blame on Hasina (5) Outside Elements were involved. My wording did not blame some group or the other , hence I think there is no bias.

Oh , I was referring to closure notice which says "The primary purpose of this question appears to be to promote or discredit a specific political cause, group or politician. It does not appear to be a good-faith effort to learn more" , I was not saying that you , @JoeW , said that. Answers might say this or that & there might be bias to promote or discredit & it might be bad-faith when it intentionally ignores some news. Question is not taking sides & is not taking names.

@Prem I am not aware of the fact people died during these events is under dispute. If there is dispute of if people did die or not, then the question can be reworded to eliminate that assumption. You can use the word "incite" in the question, nothing wrong with the word itself. I was advising what the word was doing in that particular question. Without investigations completed and results made public or any public admissions, any answer that directly answers your question would be speculative, which is something this site discourages.

Thank you for taking time to engage with me , @DavidS , I am sure you are trying to aid me. I have no issue with Speculation reason , though that is Exactly why I am asking : Does somebody know what is going on , via some Bangladeshi News Portals or via some unbiased outlets ? The answer may still be NO : That will let me know that I am not in some Censor Bubble. I only have issue with saying I am promoting somebody with bad faith , where I myself have no idea who that is.


Who ordered/orchestrated/masterminded whom to incite the killings?

About 300 people died in the protests and the circumstances that led to their deaths are currently under investigation. As of August 5, 2024:

Bangladesh Prime Minister Sheikh Hasina resigned and left the country
Monday, the army chief said, a day after almost 100 people were killed
in clashes with the police as student-led protesters demanded she step
down.
In an address to the nation, army chief Gen. Waker-Uz-Zaman said that
an interim government would be formed and that every death would be
investigated. . . .
The ouster of Hasina, 76, Bangladesh’s longest-serving leader, is a
seismic change for the majority-Muslim South Asian nation of 170
million people, where at least 300 people have been killed in recent
weeks amid a mass movement against what critics said was her
increasingly autocratic rule. . . .
On Sunday, at least 95 people, including 14 police officers, were
killed in Dhaka amid protests demanding that Hasina step down,
according to the country’s leading Bengali-language daily newspaper,
Prothom Alo. It was the deadliest day since protests began in June
over a controversial preferential quota system for public sector
jobs. While the protests began peacefully, they evolved into fury
against Hasina as the government responded with what critics said was
excessive force, which officials denied. More than 200 people had died
and thousands of others were injured before the violence Sunday, when
police fired tear gas and rubber bullets as protesters set cars and
buildings ablaze and clashed with groups they said were associated
with the government.

According to the BBC, as of August 4, 2024:

Both police and some supporters of the governing party were seen
shooting at anti-government protesters with live ammunition. Police
also used tear gas and rubber bullets.
The total death toll since the protest movement began in July now
stands at over 280.
A nationwide overnight curfew has been in place since 18:00 (12:00
GMT).
The UN's human rights chief, Volker Türk, called for an end to the
"shocking violence" and urged restraint from Bangladeshi politicians
and security forces.
He expressed particular concern over a mass march planned in Dhaka on
Monday, warning of a risk of "further loss of life and wider
destruction".
"The government must cease targeting those participating peacefully in
the protest movement, immediately release those arbitrarily detained,
restore full internet access, and create conditions for meaningful
dialogue," Mr Turk added.
The continuing effort to suppress popular discontent, including
through the excessive use of force, and the deliberate spread of
misinformation and incitement to violence, must immediately cease," Mr
Türk added.
Amid calls for her resignation, Ms Hasina sounded defiant. Speaking
after a meeting with security chiefs, she said the protesters were
"not students but terrorists who are out to destabilise the nation".
On Sunday, Law and Justice Minister Anisul Huq told the BBC’s Newshour
programme that authorities were showing “restraint”.
“If we had not shown restraint, there would have been a bloodbath. I
guess our patience has limits,” he added.
In the capital, Dhaka, access to internet on mobile devices has been
suspended.
Deaths and injuries have been reported across the country, including
the northern districts of Bogra, Pabna and Rangpur.
Thousands of people gathered in a main square in Dhaka and there have
been violent incidents in other parts of the city.
“The whole city has turned into a battleground,” a policeman, who
asked not to be named, told the AFP news agency. He said a crowd of
several thousand protesters had set fire to cars and motorcycles
outside a hospital.
Asif Mahmud, a leading figure in the nationwide civil disobedience
campaign, called on protesters to march on Dhaka on Monday. "The time
has come for the final protest", he said.
Students Against Discrimination, a group behind the anti-government
demonstrations, urged people not to pay taxes or any utility bills.
The students have also called for a shutdown of all factories and
public transport.
Around 10,000 people have been reportedly detained in a major
crackdown by security forces in the past two weeks. Those arrested
included opposition supporters and students.
Some ex-military personnel have expressed support for the student
movement, including ex-army chief General Karim Bhuiyan, who told
journalists: “We call on the incumbent government to withdraw the
armed forces from the street immediately.
He and other ex-military personnel condemned "egregious killings,
torture, disappearances and mass arrests". . . .
Students took to the streets last month over a quota that reserved one
third of civil service jobs for relatives of the veterans of
Bangladesh’s independence war with Pakistan in 1971.
Most of the quota has now been scaled back by the government following
a government ruling, but students have continued to protest, demanding
justice for those killed and injured. . . .
Ms Hasina called in the military last month to restore order after
several police stations and state buildings were set on fire during
the protests. The Bangladeshi army chief, Gen Waker-Uz-Zaman, held a
meeting with junior officers in Dhaka to assess the security
situation.
“The Bangladesh army has always stood by the people and will continue
to do so for the interest of people and in any need of the state," Gen
Zaman said, according to a release by the Inter Services Public
Relation Directorate.
Bangladeshi media say most of those killed in last month’s protests
were shot dead by police. Thousands were injured.
The government argues that police opened fire only in self-defence and
to protect state properties.

So, we know that the deaths happened in many incidents over several weeks, and each one of those will probably have to be investigated individually. The rules of engagement for police and security forces probably evolved over that time period and probably were not set on a centralized basis in the case of police. Local police chiefs and middle management police officers and security force officers ultimately made decisions on a case by case basis.
While investigations will reveal what happened in Bangladesh over the last few weeks, given the examples of similar events in history, it is unlikely that all or even most of the deaths were ordered/orchestrated/masterminded by someone. These weren't pre-planned assassinations.
They were law enforcement and security enforcement forces responding to protests that grew to a point where they were clearly violating the law. It is entirely plausible that they used excessive and/or illegal force to respond to the incidents. Individual units probably responded more or less as their limited training for these kinds of incidents told them to, unless emotions or fear of imminent harm to themselves got in the way. But we probably won't know for months. It is much easier to count the dead or injured than it is to figure out the circumstances that led to the deaths and injuries and who was responsible.
There is a good chance that there will never be a definitively and universally accepted narrative of what happened in many of these cases.

Thanks for sharing this , making some things clear though a lot is still very unclear !

The latest development in the overall situation is that according to an August 6, 2024 New York Times news article: "The president of Bangladesh on Tuesday appointed Muhammad Yunus, a pioneer in microfinance and a Nobel laureate, to oversee an interim government, accommodating demands by protesters and offering a reprieve for a country scarred by violence. The plans for a new government were announced a day after Bangladesh’s authoritarian leader, Sheikh Hasina, resigned and fled the country amid a popular uprising." https://www.nytimes.com/2024/08/06/world/asia/bangladesh-government.html
